# Conversion from C++ to C# - Iterator issue

Tags: c#, c++

Please help.

I have to convert some old C++ code to C# and have problems with an iterator conversion.
Here's the C++ code:

```
// list<int> myList
for(list<int>::iterator iter = myList.begin(); iter != myList.end() and not end;)
{
    int element = *it;
    //
    ... do something
    //                       
    iter++;
    if(not end)
    {
        myList.push_back(element);
        myList.pop_front();
    }
}
```

I tried to convert it directly 1:1 to C# ...

```
// List<int> myList;
foreach (int element in myList)
{
    //
    ... do something
    //                       
    if (!end)
    {
        myList.Add(element);
        myList.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

... but I got an InvalidOperationException, complaining the iterator won't work as the list is modified with `Add/RemoveAt`...

So my second attempt is to do it without the iterator:

```
// List<int> myList;
for (int iter = 0; iter < myList.Count && !end;)
{
    int element = myList[it];
    //
    ... do something
    //                       
    iter++;
    if (!end)
    {
        myList.Add(element);
        myList.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

But now I'm not sure if the C# code will exactly behave the same as the C++ code?
What will happen to the iterator in C++ when using `push_back` and `pop_front`? Will it stay on the same element?
Or do I need to adapt the C# code and execute another `iter++` next to `Add/RemoveAt`?

Comment: As far as I know C++ `std::list` and C# `list` are completely different structures. So don't expect behaviour to be similar.

Comment: I don't expect it. That's why I ask :)
But in this case the only interesting thin is: what happens to the iterator in C++ when using `push_back` and `pop_front`? When I know this, then I'll manage it in C# accordingly.

Comment: Since `iter` is an index in the C# code, and you remove the first element of the list, you should have a `--iter` after the `RemoveAt` call to keep it referring to the same element.

Comment: Good point!  Does the iterator in the C++ code also refer to the same element after using `pop_front`?

Comment: If you wanted a 1-to-1 convertion from C++ to C#, you should've used `LinkedList<int>` instead of `List<int>`. `LinkedList` is more of the less the same data structure as C++ `std::list`

Comment: what is end in your c# code?

Comment: it's a condition to end the loop. It is set somewhere in the `do something` section... It should not have influence on my question hat the C++ iterator does when pushing and popping elements...

Answer (score 0):

If you use an enumerator (implicitly via foreach or explicitly via GetEnumerator) then you are limited to not being able to modify the collection. Also, as ALX23z pointed out, the equivalent in C# to std::list is LinkedList, not List:

```
        LinkedList<int> myList = new LinkedList<int>();
        myList.AddLast(1);
        myList.AddLast(2);
        myList.AddLast(3);
        bool end = false;
        for (int iter = 0; iter < myList.Count && !end; iter++)
        {
            int element = myList.ElementAt(iter);

            //
            //... do something
            //                       

            if (end)
                break;

            myList.AddLast(element);
            myList.RemoveFirst();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`Queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-6.0) seems like it does what you're looking for.  I may be misreading it but I think the C++ example doesn't exit until `end` is set to true because `myList.end()` keeps being set one element further when they are pushed back.

```
Queue<int> intQueue = new Queue<int>(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
for(bool end = false; !end && intQueue.TryPeek(out int element);)
{
    //do stuff
    if(end) break;
    intQueue.Enqueue(intQueue.Dequeue());
}
```